# Uncaught Syntax Error Unexpected Token :

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I am trying to reference the last 30 elements of an array. The objects in the array are GoogleMap Markers. When I try to access any range, I get the error message in the title. I can, however, successfully access any individual value within the array. Why am I getting an error with ranges? (The error is at the last line of the code shown)

```
      var inBounds = Array(); 
      console.log(north + " " + east + "and " + south + " " + west)
      for (i=0;i<mapMarkers.length;i++) {
      myMark = mapMarkers[i]
      if (myMark.getPosition().lat() > south &&
          myMark.getPosition().lat() < north &&
          myMark.getPosition().lng() > west &&
          myMark.getPosition().lng() < east){
        inBounds.push(myMark)
      }
      }
      latestIn = inBounds[-30:]
```

Comment: `[-30:]` is not JavaScript syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not support any such syntax.

Instead, call `.slice()`.

Comment: [MDN slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)